# Angular - validation messages for a form input directive with isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, binding, angularjs-directive, custom-component

I think I am slowly going insane. What seems like a simple problem is giving me a headache :(

I have a form with a custom input element directive using isolate scope.

I simply want to able to display a error message based on the validity of the input elements "required" attribute but I seem to be going round in circles. I am not quite understanding the binding in this scenario.

Please take a look at my fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/brogueady/zwbbLggL/

I would expect the error message "Invalid" to appear to the right of the input field because it is empty.

The HTML is

```
<div ng-app="UIComponents">
<form ng-submit="formSubmit()" name="vrmForm" >
    <at-input name="registration" label="Registration" form="vrmForm" model="vrmLookup.registration" minlength="3" required>
    </at-input>
</form>
</div>
```

The JS is

```
uiComponents.directive('atInput', function () {
    return {
        // use an inline template for increased
        template: '<div>{{label}}</div><input name="{{name}}" required type="text" ng-model="model"/>  <span class="error" ng-show="form.{{name}}.$error.required">Invalid</span>',
        // restrict directive matching to elements
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            name: '@',
            form: '=',
            model: '=',
            label: '@'
    },
    compile: function(element, attr) {
        var input = element.find('input');

        if (!_.isUndefined(attr.required)) {
            input.attr("required", "true");
        }

    }
};
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $scope.form.**name** property cannot be an angular binding expression.  Return a template function instead from your directive and build the template string:

```
    template: function($element, $attr) {
        return '<div>{{label}}</div><input name="' + $attr.name + '" required type="text" ng-model="model"/>  <span class="error" ng-show="form.' + $attr.name + '.$error.required">Invalid</span>';
    },
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u8270grw/)

Comment: That definitely solves this particular problem. Thank you. Instead of having an expression in the ng-show, do you know why this will also not work?  ng-show="form.registration.$error.required"

Comment: The name of the form + the name of the field with ngModel is what's stored on $scope. That is how Angular works - there is nothing special you need to do for this to work